# What's the correct way to create a subclass of a MFC control?

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi

We layout dialogs using the resource editor. So say I have a RichEditCtrl called IDC_RICH. And I want to link it to an instance of a custom class `CMyRichEditCtrl : CRichEditCtrl`, without losing the ability to set properties on it in resource editor.

What's the right way? You can certainly get some functionality by creating a DDX-linked variable, and changing the type to `CMyRichEditCtrl`. But in some cases I see people calling code like:

```
m_Rich.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_RICH, this));
```

What's the difference?

**EDIT:** One problem I'm seeing is that when I override Create(Ex) methods, they don't get called. It's kind of like the control is already created by the time my object gets linked to the resource identifier, pehaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The windows you put on a dialog with the resource editor are created using CreateWindow(Ex) with the first argument set to the class name that is specified in the .rc file. The DDX_ mechanism then associates this instantiated window with the dialog class member in DoDataExchange().

MFC is a layer over Win32 but MFC development doesn't completely shield you from Win32. It's more like a bunch of classes and methods that take away some of the drudgery of MFC and provide some form of object-orientedness. The methods of MFC object aren't the ones that are doing the real work, and much of the framework does things under the hood and doesn't notify the 'upper layer' (i.e., MFC objects) unless that is explicitly hooked up. Create() is such a method that is only there if you want to manually create a control, it's not called by MFC when the object is created. (this is a generalization because sometimes it is, but that's outside of the scope of this discussion).

Comment: By class-name you mean the Window class, not the C++ class? If I create a custom control with its own Window class name, will it still let me alter the base properties in resource editor? Or just show up as a big grey box?

Comment: Yes, window class, the first parameter to CreateWindow(). You can't put custom control in the resource editor without coding explicit support for it. That's what the 'Custom Control' entry is for in the VS Toolbox. You can set a few properties, like enabled and caption, but that's very basic. (by 'custom control' I mean 'derived from CWnd', not from another control; if you do that, you can set the properties in the resource editor, because the resource editor will not know about the new control or that control's window class name).

Answer (score 7):

`DDX_Control()` does `SubclassWindow()` under the hood. `SubclassDlgItem` is a shortcut for `SubclassWindow(GetDlgITem())`. Usually (broad generalisation here) the people using `SubclassWindow` are the ones who picked up that habit before `DDX_Control` existed (pre-1995 or so?) and never really got into MFC-mode, or people who copy and paste their programs together from blog snippets left and right.

So, use `DDX_Control()` for clarity, although it will technically not make a difference if you use `SubclassDlgItem()`.

Answer (score 2):

1> For controls that you put on a dialog with the resource editor, used DDX_Control:

```
class CMyDlg : public CDialogEx
{

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX); // DDX/DDV support

public:
    CRichEditCtrl m_Rich;
};

void CMyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_RICHEDIT1, m_Rich);
}
```

2> For controls that create manually:

`CRichEditCtrl m_Rich;
 m_Rich.Create(...);
 m_Rich.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_RICH, this));`