# OnSelectionChanged not getting called

Tags: c++, mfc

Header:

```
#pragma once

class AlarmsList : public CVSListBox
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(AlarmsList)

public:
    AlarmsList();
    virtual ~AlarmsList();
    void OnAfterAddItem(int index);
    void OnSelectionChanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnDtnDatetimechangeDatetimepicker1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
};


void AlarmsList::OnAfterAddItem(int index)
{
    GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDC_TIMEPICK)->EnableWindow(true);
    LOGIC->addAlarm();
    LOGIC->changeSelection(index);
}

void AlarmsList::OnSelectionChanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
}
```

OnAfterAddItem gets called when i add a new item but OnSelectionChanged NEVER gets called how much i even try.

Linking it trough a message map neither dosnt work:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(AlarmsList, CVSListBox)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(AlarmsList, CVSListBox)
    ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST, OnSelectionChanged)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I create the AlarmsList object using the create function.

Source code and project: http://www.filedropper.com/clockmaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didnt help :/.

Tried both parent property page and that property pages dialog.

Overloading dosnt work either :/, it does for OnAfterAddItem tough.
And yes I'm then using the same parameters as the virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I think the LVN_ITEMCHANGED notification is sent to the parent window. Put the handler and the message map entry int your dialog/window that is the parent of the list box.

Comment: Didnt help :/.

Tried both parent property page and that property pages dialog.

Overloading dosnt work either :/, it does for OnAfterAddItem tough. And yes I'm then using the same parameters as the virtual function.

Comment: Next thing would be to use Spy++ to verify that the control is indeed sending the notification. After that, break into CWnd::OnWndMsg or CWnd::Notify and see how the message is being propagated/handled.

Comment: Yes it is indeed sending a LVN_ITEMCHANGED. How can i debug the functions? Finding all references to OnWndMsg only gives me the declaration.

Comment: You are free to take a look at the source, I'm giving up now. This homework was supposed to be turned in tonight. I cant find anyway to debug MFC source code. Cant find anything in the project settings, and what i can find doesn't work. Reinstalling visual studio neither doesn't help.

Comment: If in doubt, look at the header files...

Add this function to AlarmsList class, it's virtual (from CVSListBoxBase):

void OnSelectionChanged(); // no arguments, no

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the functions in the CVSListBoxBase class.In this class, the signature of OnSelectionChanged function requires no arguments.
You can find the declaration of the CVSListBoxBase class in afxvslistbox.h.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at some of my own MFC code that uses list boxes, and the following works;

```
CMyListBox : public CListBox
{
}

class CMyDialog : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CMyDialog(CFeatureDoc* pFeatureDoc,BOOL SheetLayout = FALSE,CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    //{{AFX_DATA(CMyDialog)
    enum { IDD = IDD_MY_DIALOG };
    CMyListBox  m_MyListBox;
    //}}AFX_DATA


// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CMyDialog)
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CMyDialog)
    afx_msg void OnSelChangeListBox();
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

void CMyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
        CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CMyDialog)
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MY_LIST_BOX, m_MyListBox);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyDialog)
    ON_LBN_SELCHANGE(IDC_MY_LIST_BOX, OnSelChangeListBox)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMyDialog message handlers


void CMyDialog::OnSelChangeListBox() 
{
}
```

If you want to have your own control process messages from a dialog, you may want to subclass it.  See this related question [What's the correct way to create a subclass of a MFC control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250970/whats-the-correct-way-to-create-a-subclass-of-a-mfc-control)